# On speed limit in SLAM

Tags: slam, navigation, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I am a ROS beginner. I am doing SLAM of turtlebot 3 (waffle) in the ubuntu 16.04, ros (kinetic) personal computer environment.

I'd like to limit the speed of the robot in real time during SLAM.
So there are two questions.
First, what is the difference between max_vel_x and max_trans_vel of dwa_local_planner_params?
Second, is it possible to change the values of max_vel_x and max_trans_vel in real time using local cost map information?
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/308667/on-speed-limit-in-slam/) by [saito](https://answers.ros.org/users/37890/saito/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2018-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. max_vel_x is how fast your robot can move in x axis, and max_trans_vel is how fast your robot can move.
2. I tried changing these two params in real time by using "rosparam set", but seems like the real velocity of robot didn't affect by it. So I think the answer would be no. I think there are also speed limits in robot's description files so maybe you want to consider them too.

If my answer was wrong please tell me and I will delete it.

---

Originally posted by [Hui Zhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/38496/hui-zhang/) with karma: 16 on 2018-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-11-16**:
you are correct about 1. `max_vel_x` is only the x-component, `max_trans_vel` is the "vector" in x and y.

about 2: Typically, the parameter is not used to dynamically adapt parameters on the fly (nodes can be implemented like that, but typically aren't. ...

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-11-16**:
The [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/Parameter%20Server) states:

> As it is not designed for high-performance, it is best used for static, non-binary data such as configuration parameters.

For dynamically changing parameters, there is a tool called `dynamic_reconfigure`. ...

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-11-16**:
This allows what you want to achieve, when it is implemented in the node. See the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure) about that.

`dwa_local_planner` supports this, so calling `dynparam set` should work. Alternatively, use the `rqt_reconfigure` GUI tool

**Comment by [Hui Zhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/38496/hui-zhang/) on 2018-11-17**:
Thank you my friend

**Comment by [saito](https://answers.ros.org/users/37890/saito/) on 2018-11-20**:
thank you.Please let me know if you can freely move on what you did with the parameters.or,please tell me if there is any way to dynamically change the speed of the robot in SLAM in other ways.